# Rails 4 - Saving/deleting with one-to-one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, associations, rails-migrations

I'm building an application where I have one-to-one relationship, Reservation 'has_one' Order. **Now my question is, how can I delete Reservation from the DB if a user decides to not completing the form for Order?** I've tried looking up ways to do this but biggest issue is not knowing what to search for.

Currently my create action saves the Reservation once the form is submitted and then redirects to the form for Order payment to be completed.

Comment: Should a `Reservation` always have an `Order`?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of worrying about deleting a Reservation if an order isn't complete, why not just prevent creation of the Reservation in the first place?

```
class Reservation
   has_one :order
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :order
   validates_presence_of :order
```

Consider combining the creation of both objects into a single page, or passing params or objects between steps of your controller.

Comment: Thank you, I accept this answer because of mentioning the part about passing params or objects between the steps of the controller. I have the application set up already in a way that I can't go back and change what I have too much. I also did not want to create one single page since the form(s) would become too lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

You should create both of them at one time

I think your best option is to use `before_save` in Order model to create a Reservation

Also check for `accepts_neseted_attributes` so both of them can be created with each other